# Ajax and jquery ajax - why doesn't traditional method let me use javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Just getting to grips with ajax and noticed that when I wanted to include javascript in the  document I link to / open

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
```

then the script doesn't work. However if I use jquery ajax then the javascript I add works fine.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You're missing adding code so we can help you better, please do it

Comment: have you set up an instance of the XMLHttpRequest() ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you can't do this with just one line. jQuery has spoiled us into making it look very easy and small, but it's actually a tad more complicated.
You never start the `XMLHttpRequest`, which is the actual magic:

```
// figure out what kind of support we have for the XMLHttpRequest object
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
     //modern browsers
     req = new XMLHttpRequest();  
}
else {
    //good ol' lousy IE
    req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
```

[This page](http://blog.kevinchisholm.com/ajax-javascript/hand-coded-javascript-ajax-the-absolute-basics/) explains the steps which have to be taken for a full `XMLHttpRequest()`.